# Linked lists in payroll calculator C++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I have to write a payroll calculator program for a class and I am running into some problems. The instructor wants us to use a linked list of structures to perform operations on a collection of the data objects.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

struct Employee
{
char *fname, *lname;
double salary, bonus, deduction_percent, Deduction, Net_sal;
Employee *next;
};

int main()
{
char line[1024];
char *first, *last, *salchar, *bonuschar, *deductionchar;
double sal, bonus, deduction;
Employee *head = NULL, *tail, *newp, *curr;
tail = NULL;
newp = NULL;
curr = NULL;
cout<<"hi"<<endl;
fstream myfile ("payroll.txt", ios::in) ;

if (myfile.is_open())
{
    //we want our head to point to the first employee, so we
    //must make our first employee before we iterate
    while ( myfile.good() )
    {
        myfile.getline(line,1024);
        //reads the txt file
        first = strtok (line, " ");
        last = strtok (NULL, " ");
        salchar = strtok (NULL, " ");
        bonuschar = strtok (NULL, " ");
        deductionchar = strtok (NULL, " ");

        sal = atof(salchar);
        bonus = atof(bonuschar);
        deduction = atof(deductionchar);

        newp = new Employee;
        newp->fname = first;
        newp->lname = last;
        newp->salary = sal;
        newp->bonus = bonus;
        newp->deduction_percent = deduction;
        newp->next = NULL;

        if(head == NULL)
        {
            head = newp;

            tail = newp;
        }
        else
        {
            tail->next = newp;
            tail = newp;
        }
```

This is where I run into a problem. When I compile the program I get a segmentation fault and after putting a series of cout statements throughout the code I figured the problem was with this loop. I was wondering if there were maybe a better way to read my file, or if there is a syntax error preventing the loop from working.

```
    myfile.close();  
}
for (curr=head; curr != NULL;curr=curr->next)
{
    cout<<curr->fname << " " <<curr->lname <<" "<< curr->salary<<" "<<curr->bonus<<" "<<curr->deduction_percent<<endl;
    curr = curr->next;
}
curr = head;
newp = head;
while (curr != NULL)
{
    curr->Deduction = (curr->salary + curr->bonus) * curr->deduction_percent;
    curr->Net_sal = (curr->salary + curr->bonus) - curr->Deduction;
}

//delete all the dynamic memory in the program
curr = head;
newp = head;
while (curr != NULL)
{
    curr = curr->next;
    delete newp;
    newp = curr;
}

}
```

Comment: Good old C with streams. Be aware no one should write C++ like this in the real world. (This refering to your instructor rather than you, who should teach you how to use STL first)

Comment: `strtok` returns pointers into the `line` buffer. When line is refershed with new data, the old data is lost. When line goes out of scope, all your pointers in the struct are invalid. You have to store a copy in the struct. I recommend `std::string`

Comment: @NeilKirk Thanks for the advice! That change and a few others throughout the code killed off my errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a better way to read the file, I would strongly recommend using stringstreams (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/) it substrings between spaces. I'm not near my computer with my code so I can't give you a good example, but you can chain together stringstreams and getlines and read until the end of file. If you're using Netbeans/Visual Studios look for the debugger and set up some breakpoints and step through it, that's how I solved a lot of my problems dealing with a linked list/file streams.